# RestoreInstanceState Android Fragments

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Estoy haciendo una app donde se pueda usar la camara. La cosa es que encontre un tutorial, pero usa Activity y yo estoy usando fragments. El punto es que todo funciona perfectamente, pero me di cuenta que el metodo onRestoreInstanceState no lo tiene los fragments. ¿Hay algo similar? 
El codigo en activity es el siguiente:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("file_path", mPath);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    mPath = savedInstanceState.getString("file_path");
}
```

¿Como se hace en fragments?

Comment: Según [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5413327/5587982), puedes hacer lo mismo usando `onActivityCreated`. Ver **[un ejemplo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Layout)** en la misma página de Android.

Comment: Ya lo intente asi, me sigue dando erro, asi me quedo ´ @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            mPath = savedInstanceState.getString("file_path");
    }´

Comment: Que es lo que deseas realizar , porque el uso de onRestoreInstanceState?, sabes para que sirve ?